# Show data of whole row of a table retrieving from database

Tags: android

I have created a database and its contents are shown in a **table layout** .When I insert into the database the data is shown in the table. Up to this its working fine.But the problem is that **when i click on a row its contents are not shown** in toast(rather if i want to show in another page).only the last row is getting clicked moreover the column whose index is set at last is only shown. thanks in advance.

this is my xml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

  <TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/gradientb"
  android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
   android:shrinkColumns="*"
  android:stretchColumns="*" >


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/deliverylistbar" />

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
 </TableRow>

 <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView0"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Id"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >

    </TextView>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView1"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Items"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView2"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Location"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView3"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="PickBy"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >

    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/TextView4"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:text="Status"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:typeface="serif" >

    </TextView>
  </TableRow>
 </TableLayout>
```

now the **SampleTableActivitys.java** page is given here....

```
 public class SampleTableActivity extends Activity {
  /** Called when the activity is first created. */


SQLiteDatabase database;
private static String DBNAME = "sample.db";    
private static String TABLE = "test";

TableLayout tableLayout;
TableRow row;
TextView firstCol;
TextView secondCol;
TextView thirdCol;
TextView fourthCol;
TextView fifthCol;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.tableLayout1);

    createDB();
    insertValues();
    displayDB();
    row.setClickable(true);
    row.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), " "+row.getTag(),
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        });
}
```

the columns are created using this...

```
private void displayDB() {

database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
if(database!=null)
{
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);

    Integer index0=cursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
    Integer index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("ITEMS");    
        Integer index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("LOCATION");
        Integer index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");
        Integer index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS");
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
                row=new TableRow(this);
                row.setId(100);
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index0));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index1));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index2));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index3));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index4));
              row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

                /*Setting up the first coloumn parameters*/
                firstCol=new TextView(this);
                firstCol.setText(cursor.getString(index0));
                firstCol.setTextSize(16);
                firstCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                firstCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(firstCol); //adding coloumn to row

                /*Setting up the second coloumn parameters*/            
                secondCol=new TextView(this);
                secondCol.setText(cursor.getString(index1));
                secondCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                secondCol.setTextSize(16);
                secondCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(secondCol); //adding coloumn to row

                /*Setting up the third coloumn parameters*/
                thirdCol=new TextView(this);
                thirdCol.setText(cursor.getString(index2));
                thirdCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                thirdCol.setTextSize(16);
                thirdCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(thirdCol); //adding coloumn to row
                fourthCol=new TextView(this);
                fourthCol.setText(cursor.getString(index3));
                fourthCol.setTextSize(16);
                fourthCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                fourthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(fourthCol);

                fifthCol=new TextView(this);
                fifthCol.setText(cursor.getString(index4));
                fifthCol.setTextSize(16);
                fifthCol.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                fifthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(fifthCol);
                /*Adding the row to the tablelayout*/
                tableLayout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            database.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

the database is created here....

```
private void createDB() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try
    {
        database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        database.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF  NOT EXISTS "+ TABLE +" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, ITEMS TEXT, LOCATION TEXT, NAME TEXT, STATUS TEXT);");
        database.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("Database Creation", "Error "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things i could notice :

1. In `displayDB()`, you are assigning same Id to each row. Assign unique Ids to each one.
   You can assign unique id using something like this inside your loop :

   ```
   row.setId(increment+10);
   increment++;
   ```

   You can initialize `increment` to 100 or any other value, outside the loop.

**Edit**  : Complete Code

```
    private void displayDB() {

database=openOrCreateDatabase(DBNAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE, null);
if(database!=null)
{
    Cursor cursor=database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+  TABLE, null);
   **int increment =100;**
    Integer index0=cursor.getColumnIndex("ID");
    Integer index1 = cursor.getColumnIndex("ITEMS");    
        Integer index2 = cursor.getColumnIndex("LOCATION");
        Integer index3 = cursor.getColumnIndex("NAME");
        Integer index4 = cursor.getColumnIndex("STATUS");
        if(cursor.getCount()>0)
        {
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            do
            {
                row=new TableRow(this);

              **row.setId(increment + 10);
             increment++;**

             row.setTag(cursor.getString(index0));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index1));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index2));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index3));
              row.setTag(cursor.getString(index4));
              row.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));  

                /*Setting up the first coloumn parameters*/
                firstCol=new TextView(this);
                firstCol.setText(cursor.getString(index0));
                firstCol.setTextSize(16);
                firstCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                firstCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(firstCol); //adding coloumn to row

                /*Setting up the second coloumn parameters*/            
                secondCol=new TextView(this);
                secondCol.setText(cursor.getString(index1));
                secondCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                secondCol.setTextSize(16);
                secondCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(secondCol); //adding coloumn to row

                /*Setting up the third coloumn parameters*/
                thirdCol=new TextView(this);
                thirdCol.setText(cursor.getString(index2));
                thirdCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                thirdCol.setTextSize(16);
                thirdCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(thirdCol); //adding coloumn to row
                fourthCol=new TextView(this);
                fourthCol.setText(cursor.getString(index3));
                fourthCol.setTextSize(16);
                fourthCol.setTextColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                fourthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(fourthCol);

                fifthCol=new TextView(this);
                fifthCol.setText(cursor.getString(index4));
                fifthCol.setTextSize(16);
                fifthCol.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
                fifthCol.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                row.addView(fifthCol);
                /*Adding the row to the tablelayout*/
                tableLayout.addView(row,new TableLayout.LayoutParams(
                        LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            }while(cursor.moveToNext());
            database.close();
        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "NOT AVAILABLE", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

1. In `OnCreate()`, you are setting `onClickListener` for a row after calling displayDB(), so only last row has listener attached to it. Attach `OnClick()` to each row that you are creating and this can be done in the loop where you create rows.

Comment: thanks a lot...i can catch ur second point and i have implemented it.its working fine i.e now i can click every row.but still the same value is shown for every click.i cant get ur first point.how should i assign unique ids to each row.can u ellaborate it kindly.it wud be very helpful.thanks in advance

Comment: can u plz edit the code given by me? i would be very much grateful

Comment: its not working :( probably i have put it on the wromg place.please add it to my code.as i am a new programmer it is difficult for me to trace the wrong proceedings.so please help me

Comment: Updated answer, as its better not to change the original question.

Comment: very sorry to say its not working..still the same problem persists :( :(

Comment: So now you can see the toast for all rows but only the last column. Is it so if am getting you properly? You need to `setTag` for row only once. Ther are getting overriden, check details of `setTag`.

Comment: yes u got me ri8...then wat wil be the ri8 way to setTag ? kindly ellaborate please

Comment: You cannot use tag to retrieve all these values. Better create a object and set its members to these values. Or if you just want to display, use toast at the place where you are setting tags and can check the values. Anyways u can see them in your table right?

Comment: Still i cant solve that :( :( but thanks for your suggestions bcoz its u who helped me a lot